# Create a Table if it doesn't exists and create a sequence if it doesn't exists in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a below table if it doesn't exists.

```
create table TEST (
                id number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
                url varchar(1000) NOT NULL,  
                urlHash varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
                contentHash varchar(255),  
                modDate varchar(30),  
                contentLocation varchar(100),  
                status integer,  
                lastCrawlDate varchar(30)) ;
```

So my questions is something like this-

```
Create Table TEST if doesn't exist
```

In the same way for sequence-

```
create sequence test_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue;
```

Something like this the query will be for sequence too-

```
Create sequence test_sequence if doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  t_count INTEGER;
  v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table TEST (
            id number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
            url varchar(1000) NOT NULL,  
            urlHash varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
            contentHash varchar(255),  
            modDate varchar(30),  
            contentLocation varchar(100),  
            status integer,  
            lastCrawlDate varchar(30))';
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO t_count
    FROM user_tables
   WHERE table_name = 'TEST';

  IF t_count = 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Similarly, you can use USER_SEQUENCES to look for an existing sequence and adapt this to suit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option.

The only thing you can do is to go ahead and create the table and sequence and simply ignore the "table already exists" error.

Comment: What my application does is that- when you run it for the first time it will create the table and create the sequence also. And after that it keeps on inserting some values into oracle database. But when I will be running that application again for the second time. Then I will be getting the `table already exists` error so it will not be having any effect if I am inserting it again on that same table. The only thing I will be having is the table already exists error. That's it right?

Comment: Correct. If you want to avoid that error you can query the system views `ALL_TABLES` and `ALL_SEQUENCES` and check if your table and sequence already exists.